# Azure DevOps Audit logs Group.UpdateGroupMembership.Remove from unknown 'DirectoryServiceAddMember' Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

In my company's Azure DevOps (w/ Azure Active Directory connected)

We are seeing Azure DevOps Audit logs that appear like the following:

- Id: *redacted*
- CorrelationId: *redacted*
- ActivityId: *redacted*
- ActorCUID: *redacted*
- ActorUserId: *redacted*
- ActorUPN: *user#1*@*mycompanydomain*.com
- AuthenticationMechanism: SessionToken_Unscoped authorizationId: 85723a06-efb0-470d-9f9a-4
- Timestamp: *redacted*
- ScopeType: Enterprise
- ScopeDisplayName: *mycompany* (Organization)
- ScopeId: 696d346f-db...9a-18e120110d16
- ProjectId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
- ProjectName: *blank*
- IpAddress: *redacted*
- UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
- ActionId: Group.UpdateGroupMembership.Remove
- Data:

  {"CallerProcedure":"prc_UpdateGroupMembership","EventAuthor":"b485afd5-cb...a-ee656a460ddf","Idempotent":"True","Incremental":"True","InsertInactiveUpdates":"True","ScopeId":"6...e120110d16","Updates":[{"GroupId":"8E8CCBD3-5F...28C0F4A5010","MemberId":"DE9DB3C7-08F...97C3BE49A0","Active":false}],"GroupId":"8e8ccbd3-5f...c0f4a5010","GroupName":"**[*mycompany*]\DirectoryServiceAddMember-696d346f-db19-4572-8d9a-18e120110d16**-Group","MemberId":"de9db3...c3be49a0","MemberDisplayName":"*name of user #2 at my company*"}
- Details: *name of user #2 at my company* was removed as a member of group **[*mycompany*]\DirectoryServiceAddMember-696d346f-db19-4572-8d9a-18e120110d16**-Group
- Area: Group
- Category: Modify
- CategoryDisplayName: Modify
- ActorDisplayName: *name of user #1 at my company*

It appears as if user #1 has removed user #2 from some unknown group but we have struggled to correlate this kind of activity to real user activity.

Can any one describe what is going on?
Is this activity in Active Directory that is bubbling into Azure DevOps?
Is there any way to lookup the Human-Readable group names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any one describe what is going on? Is this activity in Active Directory that is bubbling into Azure DevOps?

This is a normal action to add a user.

*DirectoryServiceAddMember-xxx-Group* is a group created by Azure DevOps system to temporarily store the users to be added.

Once the users are actually added to the organization, given access level, or added to a real group, they are removed from *DirectoryServiceAddMember-xxx-Group*.

So this is not actually a remove user operation, but an add user operation. And nothing to do with your AAD.